# Can 2k (or in the spirit of the new year, 2k22) bugs be security risks?

Tags: exploit, microsoft

Microsoft Exchange was [recently affected](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-exchange-year-2022-bug-in-fip-fs-breaks-email-delivery/) by an issue involving the way they stored timestamps (overflow). Could this, and similar bugs, be exploited by an attacker?

Comment: Overflows can be exploited, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug causes the anti-spam and anti-malware component to fail and not deliver the mail. Since mail delivery is critical for business the workaround is to disable the protection. An attacker can rely on this component disabled in order to bypass this line of defense and get their malicious payload delivered.

Other then that there is nothing published about a direct code execution or similar allowed by this bug. All what I could find is that it was caused by converting the date to a signed int32 which then got overflowed - and thus likely some comparison failed.

As for similar bugs: there are several kinds of similar like bugs in date handling, bugs in security components which lead to disabling these, bugs in integer overflow ... some of these might be exploitable and others not, it depends on the specifics of the bug.